# How To Pass Inline JSON Instead of URL Path

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis-js-api

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering) and let me know how I can pass Javascript object like

```
var projects = [
   { "ProjectID":"15260", "Longitude":"-118.641508",  "Latitude":"51.949915" },
   { "ProjectID":"17043", "Longitude":"-125.444557",  "Latitude":"51.097552"},
   .....
   {  "ProjectID":"17088", "Longitude":"-124.160699", "Latitude":"50.897618" }
];
```

instead of the `URL` in the

```
var photos = esriRequest({
              url: "data/1000-photos.json",
              handleAs: "json"
            });
            photos.then(addClusters, error);
          });
```

As you can see the `esriRequest()` is handling  the JSON file (data/1000-photos.json) from the server but in my case I have an jQuery Ajax call which returns same data on the `.done()` and I do not want to save them on saerver.

I already tried to remove the `esriRequest()` and load the `addClusters()` into map directly like

```
map.on("load", addClusters);

 function addClusters() {
            var photoInfo = {};
            var wgs = new SpatialReference({
              "wkid": 4326
            });
  photoInfo.data = arrayUtils.map(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
      var latlng = new  Point(parseFloat(projects.lng), parseFloat(projects.lat), wgs);
      var webMercator = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(latlng);
      var attributes = {
        "Caption": p.caption,
        "Name": p.full_name,
        "Image": p.image,
        "Link": p.link
      };
      return {
        "x": webMercator.x,
        "y": webMercator.y,
        "attributes": attributes
      };
               }
    });
```

but the `photoInfo.data` is still empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  photoInfo.data = arrayUtils.map(function() {
>       for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
>       var latlng = new  Point(parseFloat(projects.lng), parseFloat(projects.lat), wgs);
> ```

I see a couple of issues here:

- You're calling `map` (which takes an array and a function) but you're only passing one argument.
- You have a `for` loop within the `map`. This makes no sense.
- You access `projects.lng` (the whole array) instead of `projects[i].lng` (the current element).
- Your objects don't have a `lng` or `lat` property (or `caption`, `full_name`, `image`, `link`).

Try something like this instead:

```
photoInfo.data = arrayUtils.map(projects, function(p) {
    var latlng = new Point(parseFloat(p.Longitude), parseFloat(p.Latitude), wgs);
    var webMercator = webMercatorUtils.geographicToWebMercator(latlng);
    var attributes = {
        "Caption": "Project ID: " + p.ProjectID
    };
    return {
        "x": webMercator.x,
        "y": webMercator.y,
        "attributes": attributes
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank melpomene! You just awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have photo field with data on photo. But this link requires cross-server accesss.

[image]